# Spring Cloud Contract - ContractVerifierTest - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, spring-cloud-contract

Small question on Spring Cloud contract please.

I am trying to write a basic contract for my Spring Actuator health endpoint.

It is a Spring Webflux 2.4.1 project with JUnit 5 Jupiter 5.7.0 where I am the server (I expose the actuator health endpoint to my clients, hence, I want to write the contract).

Therefore, I imported the actuator jar, and the contract verifier:

```
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
```

I just wrote one simple contract in my resource folder, deleting everything else:

```
request:
  method: GET
  url: /actuator/health
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
response:
  status: 200
```

When running mvn clean install, I get :

```
target/generated-test-sources/contracts/org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/tests/ContractVerifierTest.java:[3,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: package org.junit

target/generated-test-sources/contracts/org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/tests/ContractVerifierTest.java:[4,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Rule
  location: package org.junit

target/generated-test-sources/contracts/org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/tests/ContractVerifierTest.java:[15,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.ContractVerifierTest
```

What might be the root cause, and how to fix it please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you've picked the latest Boot and not the latest Spring Cloud Contract version that assume that you're using JUnit5 and your imports show that you're generating a JUnit4 test class. Either set the `testFramework` property to `JUNIT5` or migrate to the latest Spring Cloud Contract 3.0.0 plugin that uses JUNIT5 by default.

Comment: Both solutions worked. Many thanks Marcin